# "this" is null in firebase query function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

In componentDidMount, the first console.log(this) gives me the right response("ThumbNail {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}")

but when used in the firebase query (i.e. orderbyChild) its console.log(this) returns null. I am trying to use the function "this.handleArticle" in the query but I keep getting this error "Cannot read property '_handleArticle' of null".

```
componentDidMount() {
            //adds the change listener to listen to changes in TeamStore
            TeamStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
            // triggers updateArticle
            // bind article to current state.name
            this._updateArticle();
            console.log(this); //this one is right

        //get new article as notification
        var teamResRef = new Firebase(this.props.baseUrl + this.state.name + '/results');
        teamResRef.orderByChild('timeStamp').startAt(Date.now()).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
            var newArticle = snapshot.val();

            // console.log(newArticle);
            // _handleArticle(newArticle);
             console.log(this); //this one returns null
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set `this` to callback function (because in callback `this` does not refer to `React` component `Object`), to do it you can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method like this

```
teamResRef
  .orderByChild('timeStamp')
  .startAt(Date.now())
  .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
     // code
  }.bind(this));
```

as mentioned **@David East**, you can also set `this` through fourth parameter in [`.on`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html), like this

```
teamResRef
  .orderByChild('timeStamp')
  .startAt(Date.now())
  .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      // code
   }, null, this);
```

Comment: The context `this` is different in the Firebase callback than it is in your React component. You can also set the context as the fourth param in the `.on()` function.